# WebView crash causing whole application crash

Tags: android, android-webview

I am working on developing a browser using Android built in Web View. Wherein I am facing an issue that my entire browser application crashes when I am visiting http://crashmybrowser.com for testing tab crashing on my browser. However when same test is done on chrome or opera, these browsers survive the crash and only specific tab crashes which is expected as a result of visiting the above mentioned website.
Can anyone help to understand as how can I handle this crash on my browser which is using Webview.

**Note:** I have tested that other browsers which are using Android built in webview are also crashing while visiting the http://crashmybrowser.com website.

Crash log Below:

```
    E/chromium(24703): ### WebView Version 44.0.2403.90 (code 240309050)
--------- beginning of crash
F/libc    (24703): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x7f928c4fe0 in tid 24744 (Thread-461)
I/DEBUG   ( 1078): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1078): Build fingerprint: 'google/volantis/flounder:5.0.2/LRX22L/1816899:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1078): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   ( 1078): ABI: 'arm64'
I/DEBUG   ( 1078): pid: 24703, tid: 24744, name: Thread-461  >>> net.browse.Browser <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1078): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7f928c4fe0
I/DEBUG   ( 1078):     x0   000000104530c660  x1   0000000000000003  x2   0000000000000000  x3   0000000000001be4
I/DEBUG   ( 1078):     x4   00000010e9e10140  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000007fab948000
I/DEBUG   ( 1078):     x8   0000007f929c0100  x9   0000000000000010  x10  0000007fab948e98  x11  0000000000000001
I/DEBUG   ( 1078):     x12  0000000000000001  x13  0000000000000033  x14  00000055ab3a9000  x15  003b9aca00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1078):     x16  0000007f98a4c2d8  x17  0000007fab8c4f64  x18  0000000000000000  x19  000000104530c660
I/DEBUG   ( 1078):     x20  000000104530c660  x21  0000000000000003  x22  0000000000000000  x23  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1078):     x24  0000007f929c00e8  x25  00000010452041c4  x26  0000000000000001  x27  0000007f98605444
I/DEBUG   ( 1078):     x28  00000000fffffffe  x29  0000007f928c5000  x30  0000007f977073cc
I/DEBUG   ( 1078):     sp   0000007f928c5000  pc   0000007f97701360  pstate 00000000a0000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1078):
I/DEBUG   ( 1078): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 1078):     #00 pc 0000000001a97360  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/lib/arm64/libwebviewchromium.so
W/ActivityManager( 1323):   Force finishing activity net.browse.Browser/.ui.activities.BrowseContainerActivity
I/DEBUG   ( 1078):
I/DEBUG   ( 1078): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
E/JavaBinder( 1323): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
W/ActivityManager( 1323): Exception thrown during pause
W/ActivityManager( 1323): android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
W/ActivityManager( 1323):       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager( 1323):       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
W/ActivityManager( 1323):       at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:701)
W/ActivityManager( 1323):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:852)
W/ActivityManager( 1323):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2754)
W/ActivityManager( 1323):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2611)
W/ActivityManager( 1323):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2453)
W/ActivityManager( 1323):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11511)
W/ActivityManager( 1323):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11408)
W/ActivityManager( 1323):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12087)
W/ActivityManager( 1323):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:11603)
W/ActivityManager( 1323):       at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
E/lowmemorykiller(  146): Error writing /proc/24703/oom_score_adj; errno=22
I/OpenGLRenderer( 1323): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
I/WindowState( 1323): WIN DEATH: Window{af1d060 u0 net.browse.Browser/net.browse.Browser.ui.activities.BrowseContainerActivity}
W/LocationOracleImpl( 1863): Best location was null
I/Zygote  ( 1084): Process 24703 exited due to signal (11)
I/ActivityManager( 1323): Process net.browse.Browser (pid 24703) has died
```

Answer (score 5):

Unlike Chrome or Opera, Android WebView runs in a single process, and it shares the process with your activity. If a web page starts to overuse memory (as the page you have mentioned), there is nothing you can do on the application's side to prevent a crash.

You can have multiple processes within your app (see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes) and run the activity containing WebView in a separate process. Then a crash of WebView will not affect your main app. But note that if the activity will be hosting several WebViews (e.g. as tabs of your browser), a crash in one of them will bring down the entire activity and all other WebViews it hosts. Thus, it will still not be the same as Chrome, where tabs are grouped into processes, and a crash in one tab will only bring down the tabs from the same group, but not all the tabs you have opened.

Instead of using WebView for your browser, you can try deriving it from Chromium sources, see https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions